# Is there an option to convert shell installation to pkg in Solaris?

Tags: solaris, sparc

The JRE's in oracle site for Solaris comes in `'sh'` format (java_1.6.xx.sh).
 Is there an option to convert it from `'sh'` to `'pkg'`, and then install it from this pkg on solaris using `'pkgadd'`?

Answer (score 1):

There is no conversion of an arbitrary self-extracting installer into a pkg-file. However, once installed, you can create a package out of the resulting directory structure and the files contained in it. You will also have the opportunity to add pre-install checks and post-install steps. Here is a link that could be of help: http://www.garex.net/sun/packaging/create_pkg.html

Hope this helps.